# Convert nested dictionary values to single string

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I convert the below nested dictionary values to a single string ?

```
data = {'people': {'first': {'fname': 'P1', 'lname': 'L1'}, 'second': { 'fname': 'P2', 'lname': 'L2'}}}
```

Output should be `P1 L1, P2 L2`

Here is my current code:

```
print ', '.join("%s %s" % (data['people'][person].get('fname'), data['people'][person].get('lname')) for person in data['people'])
```

Is this a efficient way for a larger set to items in people dict ? If not how to improve this  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your expression a bit short by only looping over just values and using named field in [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)(Emphasis is to keep it more readable):

```
>>> print ', '.join("{fname} {lname}".format(**p) for p in data['people'].values())
P2 L2, P1 L1
```

In Python 3.2+ this can also be done using [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map):

```
>>> print (', '.join("{fname} {lname}".format_map(p) for p in data['people'].values()))
P1 L1, P2 L2
```

---

If the keys `fname` or `lname` might be missing from the dicts then you could do something like this:

```
def get_values(dct, keys):
    return (dct.get(k) for k in keys)
...
>>> keys = ('fname', 'lname')
>>> print ', '.join("{} {}".format(*get_values(p, keys)) for p in data['people'].values())
P2 L2, P1 L1
```

---

- If number of values are huge then replace `values()` with `itervalues()`. In Python 3 use `values()` only.
- Dicts don't have any specified order, so you cannot expect the output to be `P1 L1, P2` L2 here.

Comment: Not a generic solution.

Comment: @helloV If OP's current code is working for them then it don't see why we need a generic solution here.

Comment: added sorted, `print ', '.join("{fname} {lname}".format(**p) for p in sorted(data['people'].values()))` will give `P1 L1, P2 L2`

Comment: @Skycc Without a well-defined sorting rule, sorting dicts this was is bad and unfortunately it works in Python 2. Thankfully Python 3 fixed it. OP can always sort the dicts based on the values explicitly, but I won't recommend using `sorted(data['people'].values())`.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary , i see, i did try with python 2 though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is recursive so you'll need a recursive function to obtain them

```
def get_values(data):
    values = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            values.extend(get_values(v))
        else:
            values.append(v)
    return values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = list()
for person in data["people"]:
    for val in data["people"][person].values():
        result.append(val)
    result.append(", ")
result.pop()
print(' '.join(result))
```

or

```
result = list()
for person in data["people"]:
    result.append(data["people"][person]["fname"])
    result.append(data["people"][person]["lname"])
    result.append(", ")
result.pop()
print(' '.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
one = data['people']['second'].values()
two = data['people']['first'].values()

three = one + two
three.reverse()


for each in three:
  print each,
```

I hope this what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {'people': {'first': {'fname': 'P1', 'lname': 'L1'}, 'second': { 'fname': 'P2', 'lname': 'L2'}}}


def myprint(d):
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      myprint(v)
    else:
      print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)

myprint(data)
```

Comment: I think OP wants only the values of the nested dict. But, he can tweak your solution to get the answer he needs

Comment: Need my output like this P1 L1, P2 L2. Don't need to print it separately.